# Display data based on user input in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Im quite new to python and my goal is to create a function that will ask the user to choose a department number and a year. All of the data is based on a csv file that I imported. Based on his answer I have to display him the results based on his two criteria.

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv('liste_incendies_-du_12_08_2022.csv', sep= ';' ,header=2)
swap_list = ["Numéro","Année","Type de feu","Département","Code INSEE","Commune","Lieu-dit","Code du carreau DFCI","Alerte","Origine de l'alerte","Surface parcourue (m2)"]
df = df.reindex(columns=swap_list)
df= df.sort_values('Numéro', ascending= True)
df['Commune']= df['Commune'].str.upper()
df['Lieu-dit']= df['Lieu-dit'].str.upper()
df[['Date','Hours']] = df.Alerte.str.split(" ",expand=True,)
del df["Alerte"]
df["Surface parcourue (m2)"]=df["Surface parcourue (m2)"]/1000


def firedep():
    dep = input('What department would you like:')
    if dep== "All" or dep== "all" or dep== "ALL":
        print(df.groupby(['Département','Année']).size())
    elif dep != "All" or dep!= "all" or dep!= "ALL":
        year = input('What year would you like:')
```

This is my code until this point and I cannot think of a way to achieve the goal.

Comment: Look at [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) to filter your frame based on the department number and/or year.

Comment: I have to use his input and select what he asked for from the dataframe

Comment: Correct, use boolean indexing to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `if dep.lower() == "all":` instead of `if dep== "All" or dep== "all" or dep== "ALL":`. Also for `elif` use `elif dep.lower() != "all":`